# C# Multi-panel/layer winform application

Tags: c#, layer, panels

I've been designing a pretty complicated avionics application. The thing is, it has many menu buttons to be clicked (12 to be exact) and each one of them perform a different action. For instance, one could be a login panel and the other one a PDF reader. How could I organize this programmatically?

Currently, I've been setting each item in a panel and setting it to visible or invisible, according to the active or clicked item.

How would you guys do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about adding a Dock.Top ToolStrip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx), although I'm not sure how flexible it would be in meeting your requirements. If you set your panels up with docking properties, you should be able to manage.

I would also recommend using a `UserControl` to separate code and functionality. If panels need to communicate, implement the observer/observable pattern instead of subscribing to events between user controls.

Answer (score 0):

Like IAbstract says, you should consider separating the different UI elements as UserControls. You can then do things like use a factory to construct them and add them to your window as required.

I've found this sort of approach, used with a Model-View-Presenter type pattern, works really well for WinForms apps with dynamic user interfaces.

Comment: do you have any more info on that?